# ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode, subfigures in \twocolumn

Tags: graphics, errors, subfloats, two-column

I am trying to put have subfigures that span the width of the page, while keeping the rest of my document in two columns. Thus, I am trying to exit the twocolumn mode, and use subfigures. However I get the error:

! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Below is a Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}{
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\label{ref_label1}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1}}
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\label{ref_label2}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2}}
\end{figure}
}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\end{document}
```

Having looked at other solutions to this error message, the advice is usually to remove one of the environments, but I believe that they are all necessary in this case.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `figure*` environment? It is done for that.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard I didn't know about that. Problem solved!